# How to prove this equation with complex number?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, measure-theory

I am stuck to proof this ineuqality.

$|\frac{z}{z^2-1}-\frac{z}{z^2-4}|\leq\frac{\pi}{2\eta}$ with $\eta=Im z$ (Imaginary part of complex number).  $Im z>0$

Here z is complex and $\epsilon\in(0,1)$

Comment: $\eta = \ln z$?

Comment: Whart is the $\epsilon$ doing here? Why don't you cancel it?

Comment: I have make some change. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It makes no sense, since $\operatorname{Im}z$ may be $0$. And it is trivially false if $\operatorname{Im}z<0$.

Comment: what about I define $Im z>0$